# How calculate histogram OPENCV using mask?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I need to calculate histogram on only one part of on my image, but this part has circular shape (like disc). I create mask to find that part on image

```
    cv2.rectangle(mask,(0, 0), (width, height), (0,0,0), -1)
    cv2.circle(mask,(int(avgkrug[0]),int(avgkrug[1])),radijusp2,(255,255,255),-1)
    cv2.circle(mask,(int(avgkrug[0]),int(avgkrug[1])),radijusp1,(0,0,0),-1)
```

Using code above, I found my "disc-shape" region of interest.
Now I'm trying to calculate histogram :

```
 for ch, col in enumerate(color):
    hist_item = cv2.calcHist([img],[ch],mask,[256],[0,255])
    ...
```

but got this error

```
 error: (-215) !mask.data || mask.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::calcHist
```

However, if I save mask on dics and read it using cv2.imread() then this error doesn't appear.
I also tried this use this line

```
  hist_item = cv2.calcHist([slika],[ch],mask.astype(np.uint8),[256],[0,255])
```

How can I use mask that I create to calc histogram, so I don't need to w/r from disc?

Comment: check the datatype of mask, `mask.dtype`. It should be np.uint8.

Comment: print(type(mask.dtype))             -><type 'numpy.dtype'>
print(np.result_type(mask.dtype))   ->uint8

error still appears

Answer (score 3):

The mask you create needs to be `uint8` type , so when creating the mask make it uint8, and then pass it to compute the histogram.

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
```

and now compute histogram by passing original image, and the curresponding mask.

```
hist_item = cv2.calcHist([image],[ch],mask,[256],[0,255])
```